# false || false returns true

Tags: flutter, dart

```
(idController.text.isEmpty ||passwordController.text.isEmpty)
? () => {} : 
() => {infoList[idController.text] = passwordController.text,
print(infoList[idController.text])}
```

I found `idController.text.isEmpty` and `passwordController.text.isEmpty` both are false, therefore the result should be false and ahead to print text, but it does nothing - means result is true. I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do something like this

```
var myVar (idController.text.isEmpty ||passwordController.text.isEmpty)
    ? () {} 
    : () {...}
```

`myVar` is not receiving the result of the execution of any of those functions, it's receiving the function itself. You're not executing them so it's expected that `print` doesn't run.

Your code might be an oversimplification of what you're trying to do. If I take it literally, you don't need a ternary operator.

```
if (!idController.text.isEmpty && !passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
    ...
}
```